# C++ interacting with an online SQL database?

Tags: c++, sql

I have a `PHP`-based forum wich uses an `SQL database` to store the messages and user info.
Recently I started getting interested in `C++`, so one of my first thoughts was: how would a `C++` program interact with an `online database`, say to display the threads and posts in the forum?

I'm a total newbie to `C++`, so I also would appreciate any useful links you might know.

Thanks!

EDIT: What I mean by 'online database' is a database on a remote server - not on the same machine as the running script.

Answer (score 1):

I've used DTL in the past - but its a heavy solution.  There are several libraries that wrap up the vendor/db specific API's.

It really depends on the goals of your project.  OTL looks to be the easiest to get up and running with.

- [Database Template Library](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/)
- [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/)
- [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Can these interact with a remote server (see edit)?
I'm asking because I can't see where the server is defined in SOCI